# Как в фунции раздробить число

Tags: c

.Определить, сколько раз встречается заданная цифра в заданном
числе. Например, в числе 1234231 цифра 3 встречается 2 раза, цифра 4 - 1
раз, цифра 5 - 0 раз. Обработать ситуацию, когда введенный символ не является цифрой

Comment: массив из 10 элементов. Отделять по одной цифре (`n%10`) и записывать. Ну, и переходить к следующей цифре (`n /=10`), пока они есть...

Answer (score 1):

Ну самое простое - преобразовать число в строку и пробежаться по нему и посчитать ) Я умышленно рассматриваю только положительный числа (для простоты).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdint.h>


typedef struct
{
    char* str;
    uint64_t size;
} str_t;


static uint64_t GetNumCount(uint64_t num)
{
    uint64_t size = 1;
    while (1)
    {
        if ((abs(num) / 10) > 0 )
        {
            ++size;
            num = num / 10;
        } else 
        {
            break;
        }
    }

    return size;
}


static str_t IntToCharArray(uint64_t num)
{
    str_t str_v;
    str_v.size = GetNumCount(num);

    char* s = (char*)(malloc(sizeof(uint8_t) * (++str_v.size))); // +1 '\0'

    int64_t ret = sprintf((char*)s, "%d", abs(num));
    assert(ret == (str_v.size - 1));

    str_v.str = s;

    printf("size : %ld\n", str_v.size);
    printf("%s\n", str_v.str);

    return str_v;
}


static void PrintEqual(str_t str_v)
{
    char change_ch = 'x';

    for (uint64_t i = 0; i < str_v.size; ++i)
    {
        uint64_t count = 0; 
        char selected_char = str_v.str[i];
        if (!isdigit(selected_char)) {
            continue;
        }
        for (uint64_t j = 0; j < str_v.size; ++j) {
            if (str_v.str[j] == selected_char) {
                ++count;
                str_v.str[j] = change_ch;
            }
        }
        printf("char : %c count : %ld\n", selected_char, count);
    }

}


static void FreeData(str_t str_v)
{
    if (str_v.str) {
        free(str_v.str);
        str_v.str = NULL;
        str_v.size = 0;
    }
}


int64_t main()
{
    uint64_t num = 1220333455;

    str_t str_v = IntToCharArray(num);

    PrintEqual(str_v);

    FreeData(str_v);

    return 0;
}
```